# Installing file with .pyx files replaced with .c then is killed

Tags: python, emacs, module, installation

I am trying to set up the module Despotic: https://bitbucket.org/krumholz/despotic and I have reached the point where I downloaded the repository and am trying to run the command: python setup.py install, and at first, it gave the error .pyx file type not known. That file had a .c file with the same name, so I went into the setup.py file and changed teh .pyx to .c and now when I try to install it, it spits out this:

install
*several seconds pass*

[3]+   Done            emacs setup.py

Killed

And that is it. I just need to install this module and I feel like I am so close. I just downloaded a virtual machine, so I've been downloading various programs as they become needed (numpy, scipy, matplotlib, for example), so maybe I am missing a program that is keeping despotic from working? I installed cython and pyrex hoping it would fix the fact that it didn't understand .pyx files, but that didn't work. What is going wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Killed indicates that something sent it `SIGKILL`. This is usually the kernel due to machine running out of memory. You can verify by inspecting the output of `dmesg`.

Comment: Do you have the following dependencies installed? 
`scipy >= 0.11.0
cython >= 0.20.x
matplotlib >= 1.3.x` Taken from [despotic.readthedocs.io](http://despotic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#requirements-and-dependencies)

Comment: Everything is updated to the newest version, and after 'dmesg' it says that I am out of memory. Is there an easy way to increase my storage, or do I need to create a new virtual machine? (I'm using Ubuntu on a virtual machine)

Comment: What virtual machine software are you using? Virtualbox, VmWare Workstation/ESX, etc. You should be able to expand the memory of the machine within the settings for the virtual machine. The vm will usually need to be shut down in order for the settings to take affect.